# Can a partition exist without a volume?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, diskpart

There appears to be a partition that seemingly has no volume associated to it.

Selecting the D volume (5), which contains the affected partition, results in the primary partition (2) being selected as well:

```
DISKPART> select volume 5

DISKPART> list volume

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     C   OS           NTFS   Partition    914 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 1         ESP          FAT32  Partition    150 MB  Healthy    System
  Volume 2         WINRETOOLS   NTFS   Partition    990 MB  Healthy    Hidden
  Volume 3         Image        NTFS   Partition     14 GB  Healthy    Hidden
  Volume 4         DELLSUPPORT  NTFS   Partition   1380 MB  Healthy    Hidden
* Volume 5     D   PM981a       NTFS   Partition    476 GB  Healthy
  Volume 6     E   misc         NTFS   Removable     57 GB  Healthy

DISKPART> list partition

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Reserved            15 MB    17 KB
* Partition 2    Primary            476 GB    16 MB
```

Then, selecting the reserved partition (1) clears the selected volume:

```
DISKPART> select partition 1

DISKPART> list partition

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
* Partition 1    Reserved            15 MB    17 KB
  Partition 2    Primary            476 GB    16 MB

DISKPART> list volume

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     C   OS           NTFS   Partition    914 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 1         ESP          FAT32  Partition    150 MB  Healthy    System
  Volume 2         WINRETOOLS   NTFS   Partition    990 MB  Healthy    Hidden
  Volume 3         Image        NTFS   Partition     14 GB  Healthy    Hidden
  Volume 4         DELLSUPPORT  NTFS   Partition   1380 MB  Healthy    Hidden
  Volume 5     D   PM981a       NTFS   Partition    476 GB  Healthy
  Volume 6     E   misc         NTFS   Removable     57 GB  Healthy
```

Re-selecting partition 2 sets volume 5 back to being selected.

**Is there a hidden or implicit volume that partition 1 is associated to, or can one exist independently?**

Here are some screens (The OEM D drive was imaged onto the larger C drive, so may be whey the labels in Disk Management are missing):

**Disk Management**

[image]

**Macrium**

[image]

Comment: AFAIK there will only be a volume for a partition if it is "usable" (or "recognized") by/in Windows. For example, partitions with Linux-specific type code / GUID do not get volumes either. So what you are seeing / experiencing is completely normal. I don't have a concrete definition of "usable" for you (since Windows is always obscure anyway), but essentially it's "one that you can format (without recreating) in Windows".

Comment: Truth is, it might be the only reason to have the concept of "volume".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 15 MB space you see is probably the
[Microsoft Reserved Partition (MSR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Reserved_Partition):

> A Microsoft Reserved Partition (MSR) is a partition of a data storage
> device, which is created to reserve a portion of disk space for
> possible subsequent use by a Windows operating system installed on a
> separate partition. No meaningful data is stored within the MSR;
> though from the MSR, chunks may be taken for the creation of new
> partitions, which themselves may contain data structures.
>
> The GUID Partition Table (GPT) label for this partition type is
> E3C9E316-0B5C-4DB8-817D-F92DF00215AE.

You may check its GUID to verify if it's indeed the MSR.

This pseudo-partition is not formatted and doesn't have a
file-system, therefore is not counted as a volume by diskpart.
The term "volume" means a partition that is formatted with a
file-system.

The
[diskpart documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/diskpart)
says more:

> You can only give focus to a partition on the selected disk. After a partition has focus, the related volume (if any) also has focus. After a volume has focus, the related disk and partition also have focus if the volume maps to a single specific partition. If this isn't the case, focus on the disk and partition is lost.

So when you selected volume 5, it contained only one partition with a
file-system, so this was also selected.

However, when you selected the MSR, which doesn't contain a
file-system, this wasn't enough to select any volume, including
volume 5.

(I agree that the volume/partition terminology as used in diskpart is
confusing.)

Comment: *"After a volume has focus, the related disk and partition also have focus if the volume maps to a single specific partition. If this isn't the case, focus on the disk and partition is lost."* - Is this b/c a volume can span multiple partitions and disks?

Comment: I have also scratched my head regarding that phrase that looks truly scrambled. I took "maps" to mean "can be derived". I think the Microsoft documentor also got confused here by the concept of a volume that contains a volume, which isn't covered at all by the definition he himself wrote previously.

Comment: [What is the difference between a volume and a partition in Windows?](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2321843-what-is-the-difference-between-a-volume-and-a-partition-in-windows) Found that yesterday, seems everyone has their own take.

Comment: It seems that the true explanation is that the MSR doesn't count as anything and is basically treated as unallocated space.